# border collapse not working

Tags: html, css

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sWGBs/1/)

as you can see from the demo above the borders are not collapsing! i'm new to this and not sure why, any help would be much appreciated

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="images/new24/_landing/profile_slideout/contactme_icon.png"/></td>
        <td><img src="images/new24/_landing/profile_slideout/bouncerate_icon.png"/></td>
        <td><img src="images/new24/_landing/profile_slideout/analyseme_icon.png"/></td>
        <td><img src="images/new24/_landing/profile_slideout/socialme_icon.png"/></td>
        <td><img src="images/new24/_landing/profile_slideout/locateme_icon.png"/></td>
        <td><img src="images/new24/_landing/profile_slideout/dailybubble_icon.png"/></td>
        <td><img src="images/new24/_landing/profile_slideout/bouncedon_icon.png"/></td>
        <td><img src="images/new24/_landing/profile_slideout/followme_icon.png"/></td>
        <td><img src="images/new24/_landing/profile_slideout/exhibitormode_icon.png"/></td>
        <td><img src="images/new24/_landing/profile_slideout/treatsprofile_icon.png"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

 td {

    border: 1px solid red;
    background: blue;
    width: 129px;
    height: 116px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: It's because the cells are floated. Why oh *why* would you float table cells like that? Why even a table at all? Most importantly, what do you want us to help you with?

Comment: AHHH the dreaded table for non-tabular data.... Mine Eyes Hurt!(Also died a little inside)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you mark-up your content like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="images/new24/_landing/profile_slideout/contactme_icon.png"/></li>
    <li><img src="images/new24/_landing/profile_slideout/bouncerate_icon.png"/></li>
    <li><img src="images/new24/_landing/profile_slideout/analyseme_icon.png"/></li>
    <li><img src="images/new24/_landing/profile_slideout/socialme_icon.png"/></li>
    <li><img src="images/new24/_landing/profile_slideout/locateme_icon.png"/></li>
    <li><img src="images/new24/_landing/profile_slideout/dailybubble_icon.png"/></li>
    <li><img src="images/new24/_landing/profile_slideout/bouncedon_icon.png"/></li>
    <li><img src="images/new24/_landing/profile_slideout/followme_icon.png"/></li>
    <li><img src="images/new24/_landing/profile_slideout/exhibitormode_icon.png"/></li>
    <li><img src="images/new24/_landing/profile_slideout/treatsprofile_icon.png"/></li>
</ul>
```

... and also consider adding `alt` attributes to each image.

Your CSS would look like this:

```
li {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: blue;
    width: 129px;
    height: 116px;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
}
```

To preserve the top and left border, add this:

```
ul {
    margin: 1px 0 0 1px;  
}
```

The margin property is the one that causes the borders to collapse on this series of elements.

[Here is a jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/mNRDb/).

Comment: hey thanks for this. but i need a border top and border left. i have been racking my brains how to do this and still not sure !

Comment: I have added the CSS rule for this to my answer - you just add an equal opposite margin to the ul element.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are floating each TD element you are causing the TDs to be treated like block elements by the renderer rather than as table-cells. Block elements have no concept of border-collapse.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position

Comment: You can achieve border-collapse using negative margins on block elements.

Comment: Thanks Sohnee, but I was referring to the CSS property "border-collapse" as is in the CSS posted and explaining why it was failing in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

move your background:blue up into the table element and comment out the collapse

```
table {
XXborder-collapse: collapse;
background: blue;
```

}

```
 td {
border: 1px solid red;
width: 129px;
height: 116px;
float: left;
position: relative;
padding: 20px;
```

}

also, **uncheck Normalized CSS** and you will see it's working but perhaps not like you thought.